# EF Core avoid duplicate addresses

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

This seems like a simple task but I still didn't find a solution.

I have a model class that represents a address and a class for orders:

```
internal class Address
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    /*fields for street, city, etc*/
}

internal class Order
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    /*other fields*/
    public Address ShipToAddress { get; set; }
    public Address BillToAddress { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, that in like 95% of the cases, the ship to and the bill to address are the same.

Even if I set both fields to the same object, Entity Framework creates 2 rows in the database containing the exact same data (except for the ID of course).

Is there a (simple) way to avoid creating those duplicates?

### EDIT

This is how the order is created / inserted:

```
var billToAddress = new Address();
var shipToAddress = billToAddress;

var order = new Order
{
    ShipToAddress = shipToAddress,
    BillToAddress = billToAddress,
};

_dbContext.Orders.Add(order);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `Attach`? How are you inserting order?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev see my edit, for simplicity I left out parts like adding order items

Comment: Try to add `_dbContext.Addresses.Attach(shipToAddress); ` before `SaveChanges`

Comment: You leave the establishment of the relation all to automatism ?  You should have two foreign keys in Order, have these columns been created ? Try saving the address first by itself with Adresses.Add(address)+ SaveChanges. Than you can be sure it has only one definite ID. I'm not sure how much this has an effect on this behaviour, but so far most navigation properties (your two addresses) I have seen, have been marked as virtual.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour occurs when the Same Address object is added to the Order object when the order object is Added to the Orders collection.

By default, when *Creating* a new object, all other navigation objects that do not have their `[Key]` fields set, are assumed that they too need to be added to the database, this pattern can happen as well with other types of lookup fields and relationships.

- In cases like yours, this will always result in two records, even though they might have been the same object reference.

There are a few solutions to this:

1. Accept this behaviour and move on, if you always assume the two records will be separate, in the user interface you can write to both records at the same time, or until the user unticks a box that says "Billing and Shipping address are the same"
2. Change the workflow so that when adding `Address` objects to the *ShipTo* or *BillTo* address they have already been committed to the database (their ID field will be set) then you can add the same Address to both fields without any issues.

   - You could even change the process so that `Order` is saved to the database first.
   - You should handle the "cancel situation", if the save on the order fails you may have to manually delete the address that was created

     - You can use *Transactions* to assist in this scenario.
   - This is a bit more involved, but you could make an `Address` *Factory* method that returns a new Address record that has already been committed to the database. Without using the factory pattern, your code might look like this:

     ```
     var order = new Order();

     var billToAddress = new Address();
     _dbContext.Addresses.Add(billToAddress);
     _dbContext.SaveChanges();

     order.ShipToAddress = billToAddress;
     order.BillToAddress = billToAddress;

     _dbContext.Orders.Add(order);
     _dbContext.SaveChanges();
     ```
3. You can override the `SaveChanges` method on the `DbContext` so that before save, you can iterate through the `Order` changes, detect when *Billto* and *ShipTo* address objects are the same, then remove one before executing `base.SaveChanges()` then add the reference back and then call `base.SaveChanges` again.

Option 1 is a design choice, making this decision means the database side is always pretty simple, the complexity is in the user interface.

Although I have done option 3 a few times in the past, I prefer option 2 (when option 1 is not acceptable) as it keeps this logic close to the other logic associated with `Order`s and `Address`es, long term option 2 is easier to maintain.

> You could look at another design pattern altogether, I like to make `Order` have a collection of `Address` records and each `Address` has an `AddressType` which is an enum:
>
> > Billing, Sender, Receiver...
>
> Then in your UI, an `Address` with `AddressType` = `AddressTypes.Billing` address is always created first, because we always need this, the user can add new address records as they want to, when only `Billing` address exists, all other address operations will use this reference.
>
> UI Validation and database constraints can be implemented to ensure that duplicate address records with the same type are no created.

Comment: I really like your alternate design pattern. I'll first try some of the other solutions you gave, but I'll keep the adresstype field in mind